# Read hex data from a file, starting at position x, terminating at first null byte (00)?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, hex, filereader

So I need to read a file that has a 'word' inside in hex (ACSII). Of course words can be of any length, but always starts at offset 0x1290. What I am trying to do is read the hex of a file starting at offset 0x1290, and continue UNTIL it encounters a null byte (00). So far all the coding I have tried seems to need a fixed length to read.

```
filePath = "C:\myfile"
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x1290;     // The starting offset
byte[] word = reader.ReadBytes(); // Must specify length within ReadBytes(e.g. 0x99)
reader.Close();`
```

After the required 'word' there can often be other hex data which is not required, however there is always a null byte after the 'word'. This is why I cannot specify a length.

Comment: But what is the question? If you're required to read a number of bytes until you reach a 0-byte, why can't you simply read from the file one byte at a time?

Comment: Could you help me with that? im pretty new to c#. I imagine i need some sort of loop, but i wouldn't be able to use a byte[] array? I also intend to take the hex string and convert it to text string for display

Answer (score 0):

use while loop:

```
filePath = "C:\myfile"
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x1290;
byte char;
byte[] result=new byte[length_of_the_word];
int i=0;

while(((byte)char=reader.Read())!=-1)
{
   result[i++]=char;
}

reader.close();
```

then replace -1 (end of file) with the end word hex, like 0x00

Comment: what do you mean [length_of_the_word], as length can be anything?

Comment: if the searched word has a constant length, just put it as a length of array, else put maximum length of the searched word

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many chars is the length of your string you should use some kind of collection that doesn't require beforehand the exact length of data to store. This seems the perfect work for a `List<byte>`

```
List<byte> bits = new List<byte>();
using(FileStream s = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile", FileMode.Open))
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(s))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x1290;
    while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        byte b = reader.ReadByte();
        if(b != 0x00)
            bits.Add(reader.ReadByte());
    }
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bits.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I tried the above mentioned, but they seem to keep coming up with errors. Anyway I figured out a loop myself and am here to share:

```
int c = 0;
int runs = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[400]; // byte array setup

// read hex values (loop) and convert to acsii string
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("C:\File", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None));
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0x1290;

while (c == 0)
{
    data[runs] = reader.ReadByte();
    if (data[runs] == 0x00)
    {
       c = 1; // stop loop at .ReadByte = 0x00
    }
    runs++;
}
reader.Close();

// hex to acsii string, removing null bytes
result = Encoding.Default.GetString(data.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray());
```

Seems to work well

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is *not* ASCII. If you want ASCII, use `Encoding.ASCII`. If not, figure out what encoding you actually need, or you're going to get into trouble. Also note that you can use `break;` to exit a loop. And there's a `bool` type that would be a better choice for the "loop variable". And `Encoding.GetString` has an argument for the amount of bytes you want to decode - try `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, runs - 1);` instead.